# Ctrl-I in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, search

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> "incremental search" feature is great in the sense that it avoids showing the Find dialog box (which obscures your screen).

However, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> does have an advantage in that it centres the code vertically in the middle of your screen.

Is there a way to make Ctrl-I centre the code in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is. So I've mapped the command "Edit.ScrollLineCenter" to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and just interchangeably hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> while scanning through the source with incremental search.